# Bug in NSFileManager (instance method is traversing symbolic link)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, alias, macos-carbon, finder

I am using `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` for copy operation. From documentation:

> Symbolic links are not traversed but are themselves copied

but this method is traversing symbolic link and copying orignal content for Symbolic links created by `ln -s`(in 10.5).
`kMDItemFSFinderFlags` is zero for alias created by `ln -s`.
`attributesOfItemAtPath:error: returns NSFileType = NSFileTypeSymbolicLink`

From [What's the difference between alias and link?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/2994/14137)

> An alias contains two pieces of information: a unique identifier of
>   the file it links to, and the path and file name of the file it links
>   to.
>
> If you rename or move a file, and then create a new file with the path
>   and file name that the file originally had, then any alias that linked
>   to the original file now links to the new file.
>
> However, if you rename or move a file without replacing it, and then
>   invoke an alias, the alias is updated to point to the new path and
>   file name, making use of the unique identifier to do so.
>
> A symbolic link, on the other hand, does not contain a unique
>   identifier to a file, and would appear as broken if the file is
>   renamed or moved and not replaced with a file of the same path and
>   file name.

when i am creating alias using

```
tell application "Finder"
    make new alias at POSIX file "/Users/test/" to POSIX file "/Applications/Safari.app"
end tell
```

`copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` is working fine and `kMDItemFSFinderFlags = 33792`.

```
attributesOfItemAtPath:error: returns NSFileType = NSFileTypeRegular;
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If this indeed a bug try using `copyfile()` (C function, man section 3) instead.

Comment: If file is symbolic link(4KB) then copyfile() is copying zero KB in 10.5. In 10.6 its working fine.

Comment: copyfile((const char *)[srcpath UTF8String], (const char *)[destpath UTF8String], state, COPYFILE_DATA | COPYFILE_XATTR | COPYFILE_STAT | COPYFILE_ACL | COPYFILE_NOFOLLOW_SRC);

Comment: Strange, copyfile() handles symlinks, suggesting the cause of the problem is something else... Does copyfile() return an error result? What is the value of `errno`? You could try to copy the link yourself with `destinationOfSymbolicLinkAtPath:error:` (a wrapper for readlink()) and `createSymbolicLinkAtPath:withDestinationPath:error:` (a wrapper for symlink()) - checking the results as you go.